# Case When syntax expression in jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to reproduce this MySQL query in jooq

```sql
select case     
when year(d.date) - p.birth_year < 5 then '<5' 
else '5+'
end as age
from partners p join departure d on d.id = p.id
```

to

```java
this.schema().select(
DSL.decode().value(dateDiff(p.BIRTHDATE , date(d.DATE)))
   .when(greaterThan(5), "above 5")
   .when(lessThan(5), "under 5")
   .otherwise("unknown").as("age"),
   .from(p)
   .join(d).on(d.ID.eq(p.ID))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is the SQL:2003 simple `CASE` expression, which allows to form something like "partial predicates" based on the case value, akin to pattern matching in other languages. This is not yet supported in jOOQ, see [Issue #3223](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3223).

Interestingly, though, your SQL example doesn't use this syntax, nor does it correspond to your suggested jOOQ API usage.  I suspect you wanted to use this syntax to avoid repeating the subtraction twice. This could be done also as follows, in SQL:

```sql
select 
  case sign(year(d.date) - p.birth_year - 5)
  when -1 then '<5'
  when  0 then '5+'
  when  1 then '5+'
          else 'unknown' end AS age
from partners p join departure d on d.id = p.id
```

This would translate to:

```java
Partners p = PARTNERS.as("p");
Departure d = DEPARTURE.as("d");

using(configuration)
   .select(choose(sign(year(d.DATE).minus(p.BIRTH_YEAR).minus(5)))
       .when(inline(-1), val("<5"))
       .when(inline( 0), val("5+"))
       .when(inline( 1), val("5+"))
       .otherwise(inline("unknown"))
       .as("age"))
   .from(p)
   .join(d).on(d.ID.eq(p.ID))
   .fetch();
```

This static import is implied:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: exatly what i was looking for esp the `inline(-1)` notation. Thank you for providing a clear and elaborate solution. +10 for providing the `static import` many solutions leave that part

Comment: @joseph: Thanks for your nice words. Yes indeed, `DSL.inline()` is often overlooked. Here are some more details about it: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters